# Removing extra pipes and text around them from string in Perl with regex

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I have a string like this that I'd like to process in perl.

```
hello|world|nice|to|meet|you
```

I'd like to keep the first three pipe symbols and the text around them and discard the rest of the string. So, I'd end up with this:

```
hello|world|nice|to
```

I'm thinking I want to do something like this:

```
substitute (zero or more non-pipes followed by a pipe)[3 times] followed by the rest of the string with a back reference to the piece of the regex where I matched the 3 pipes and the characters around them.
```

I'm not sure about the regex syntax for this in perl.

I can do what I want to like this:

```
$str = "hello|world|nice|to|meet|you" ;
@a = split(/\|/, $str) ;
print $a[0] . "|" . $a[1] . "|" . $a[2] . "|" . $a[3]
```

But, I'd like to see how to do this with a regex.

Comment: You are using a regex :)

Comment: `join "|", ( split /\|/ )[0..3]`

Comment: Yes, split with a regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
s='hello|world|nice|to|meet|you'
perl -pe 's/^((?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*).*/$1/' <<< "$s"
```

```
hello|world|nice|to
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `[^|]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not pipe
    - `\|`: Match a pipe
  - `){3}`: End non-capture group. `{3}` matches 3 repetitions of this group
  - `[^|]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not pipe
- `)`: End capture group #`
- `.*`: Match everything till end

**Perl Code**:

```
$str = "hello|world|nice|to|meet|you" ;

$str =~ s/^((?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*).*/$1/;

print "$str\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture with `()`:

```
$ cat foo.pl && ./foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str = "hello|world|nice|to|meet|you" ;
$str =~ s/^(([^\|]*\|){3}[^\|]*)\|.*/$1/;
print STDOUT "$str\n";
hello|world|nice|to
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all but the first 3 pipes and surrounding text can be done like :

`$txt =~ s/^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*\K.*//s;`